# My crontab run sequently less than 1 minute

Tags: linux, laravel, cron

I use crontab to run Laravel schedule, this is my cron entry:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/mailserver/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

In App/Console/Kernel.php I just write log file:

```
Log::info('Schedule excuted');
```

But in my log file, it seems run sequently in 3 seconds instead of 1 minute

[image]

Please help me, how to run cronjob slow down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cron statement you provide is telling it to run constantly. Chances are there is just a delay of 3 seconds between the log being called. If you read the scheduling docs you would see that to run every minute you need to do the following:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->call(function () {
        Log::info('Schedule excuted');
    })->everyMinute();
}
```

Source: [Scheduling Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/scheduling)